# why basic auth loops when using nginx and monit

Tags: nginx, web-server, authentication, monit, http-basic-authentication

I was trying to configure nginx so that `http://example.com/monit` will access `http://127.0.0.1:2812`, which is the url monit is listening.

Two authentication was set, via nginx(nginx.conf file) and monit(monitrc file).

Now, accessing `http://example.com/monit/`, should popup two input forms, but after entering the second one(via monit), the nginx one pops up again. 
Can anyone point out what is wrong?

(note: solving this problem is easy - turn off one basic authentication)

I tested with debian jessie. sorry if it won't reproduce

---

this is my /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf (installed from source)

```
server{
    ...
    auth_basic "restricted"
    auth_basic_user_file /home/user/.htpasswd;
    location /monit/ {
        rewrite ^/monit/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:2812;
    }
}
```

This configuration requires the user to enter the user/password to access any file in this server directive. if the uri starts with /monit/, it enteres the location directive and it is passed to `127.0.0.1:2812`. simple.

Then in /etc/monitrc, I set a basic authentication.

```
set httpd port 2812 and
    allow 127.0.0.1      # allow access only from localhost
    allow admin:monit    # user:password
```

this makes monit accessible from localhost only.

Comment: HTTP basic auth use one header `Authorization` and it can't contain two passwords simultaneously.